# VBScript *unintentionally* pauses on background

Tags: vbscript

For a brief description of the code I have, I want to keep in track a certain app named 'CostX.exe' if it closes and opens and I log it on a file called CostXLog.txt
I keep it on an infinite loop. The problem is, i dont know why but it works for a brief period when Im not doing anything productive, but when I do, the script just *pauses* or should I say it doesnt work anymore though it still stays in the background.
This should be its desired output.

> Opened at: 4/7/2021 9:00:52 AM
>
> Closed at: 4/7/2021 9:07:56 AM
>
> CostX was opened for 7 minutes and 4 seconds.

But when I say I do anything productive, the output stays at

> Opened at: 4/7/2021 9:00:52 AM

This is my code

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1, ForAppending = 8
Dim i, processName, strComputer
Dim fso, inName, outName, shell, curDir, objWMIService, colProcessList
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
curDir = shell.CurrentDirectory
outName = curDir & "\CostXLog.txt"
Dim counter1, counter2, initialOpen
Dim minDiff, secDiff
Dim timedate1, timedate2
timedate1 = Date() & " " & Time()
initialOpen = 0
counter1 = 0
counter2 = 1
'msgbox curDir
strComputer = "."

processName = "CostX.exe"

Dim newFile, outputFile 
newFile = Not fso.FileExists( outName )

while(true)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select Name from Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '" & processName & "%'")
    Set outputFile = fso.OpenTextFile( outName, ForAppending, True )
    if initialOpen = 0 Then
        outputFile.WriteLine "Ignore time after this line"
        initialOpen = 1
    else
        
        If colProcessList.count>0 then
            If counter1 = 0 Then
                outputFile.WriteLine "Opened at: " & Date() & " " & Time()
                timedate1 = Date() & " " & Time()
                counter1 = 1
                counter2 = 1
            End If
            
        else
            If counter2 = 1 Then
                outputFile.WriteLine "Closed at: " & Date() & " " & Time()
                timedate2 = Date() & " " & Time()
                minDiff = DateDiff("s", timedate1, timedate2)/60
                secDiff = DateDiff("s", timedate1, timedate2)
                outputFile.WriteLine "CostX was opened for " & Fix(minDiff) & " minutes and " & secDiff - (Fix(secDiff/60) * 60) & " seconds."
                counter2 = 0
                counter1 = 0
            End If
        End if
    End If
    outputFile.Close
    WScript.Sleep 50
wend

Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set colProcessList = Nothing
```

PS: I am not a programmer, I have assembled that from many sources in the internet, I do understand a bit, but some of the parts in there, I really dont have any idea, I just know that they work as I want them to. So i guess someone could provide me an idea as to how to keep it running no matter what I do in my computer. Is there anything wrong with what I did in the code?
I have also done a batch script with the same intended purpose, the issue is the same, it was also made with a loop, and it pauses when I am busy working.

Comment: You admit you have no idea what portions of your code do. So you are effectively asking others to debug it for you. That is not what SO is for, hence you will get downvotes.

Comment: To be precise, that "some parts I dont understand" are the values for objWMIService & colProcessList, I really cant understand it that much, the rest of the code, I have done it myself. I am not really asking for a debug, if the problem can be pointed out by just looking at the code itself, then I will accept any observations you or others may have. Or that maybe, the problem is in the OS itself? Is there some kind of limitations in the OS by using infinitely looping scripts?

Comment: I don't have formal education on programming as I am a graduate of a different field, I only self studied them. I will respect any comments that you have, Im sorry if it seems that I am just asking others to just debug this for me. As i have said in the last lines of my post, I only want thoughts or feedbacks on my code, any small thing may help me to understand why my problem is happening. Thank you.

Comment: @trexed1509 I tried the code replacing the CostX.exe with notepad.exe and checking the logfile in notepad++ and is working for me. When you say `do anything productive` does it mean working with this exe or working with other applications?

Comment: In my case, it was working using that same application. The weird thing is, the code is really working if I just test it like I close and open the application, the script will really populate the CostXLog.txt file as intended, however, if Im getting into my work to deep, say I will be busy working for around 20mins, the script doesnt populate the .txt file anymore after I close and open the application. I hope my explanation is clear. Thanks @Flakes for taking the time to answer.